# Scraping data from a table and storing it in csv file

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would want to scrap the data from this website and store it in csv file in this manner.

[image]

But when I try to scrap the data it is not stored in exact format. All the data is stored in the 1st column itself. I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Link : https://pce.ac.in/students/bachelors-students/

Code:

```
import csv  # file operations
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup  # lib for pulling data from html/xmlsites
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq  # lib for sending and rec info over http
Url = 'https://pce.ac.in/students/bachelors-students/'
pageHtml = uReq(Url)
soup = soup(pageHtml,"html.parser") #parse the html
table = soup.find_all("table", { "class" : "tablepress tablepress-id-10 tablepress-responsive-phone" })
f = csv.writer(open('BEPillaiDepart.csv', 'w'))
f.writerow(['Choice Code', 'Course Name', 'Year of Establishment','Sanctioned Strength'])  # headers
for x in table:
    data=""
    table_body = x.find('tbody') #find tbody tag
    rows = table_body.find_all('tr') #find all tr tag
    for tr in rows:
        cols = tr.find_all('td') #find all td tags
        for td in cols:
            data=data+ "\n"+ td.text.strip()
            f.writerow([data])
#print(data)
```

Comment: Add  f.writerow(data+"\n") in your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create variable data in each tr label,you can try like this:

```
import csv  # file operations
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup  # lib for pulling data from html/xmlsites
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq  # lib for sending and rec info over http
Url = 'https://pce.ac.in/students/bachelors-students/'
pageHtml = uReq(Url)
soup = soup(pageHtml,"html.parser") #parse the html
table = soup.find_all("table", { "class" : "tablepress tablepress-id-10 tablepress-responsive-phone" })
with open('BEPillaiDepart.csv', 'w',newline='') as csvfile:
    f = csv.writer(csvfile)
    f.writerow(['Choice Code', 'Course Name', 'Year of Establishment','Sanctioned Strength'])  # headers
    for x in table:
        table_body = x.find('tbody') #find tbody tag
        rows = table_body.find_all('tr') #find all tr tag
        for tr in rows:
            data=[]
            cols = tr.find_all('td') #find all td tags
            for td in cols:
                data.append(td.text.strip()) 
            f.writerow(data)
            print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you search the meaning of csv, you would find it means comma separated values, however I don't see any commas in your text while appending it to the file.